# CSS: Entries in Lists Don't Start New Lines

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with my unordered lists because the list I'm trying to create is this:

- A
- B

But I'm instead getting a list which is all on one line, and the bullet point for B overlaps A. Here's the relevant piece of my CSS code:

```css
ul.c li {
  list-style-type: disc;
  background: #F2D7D5;
  font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

[Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCbyr.png)

EDIT:
Here's all the other code I have that relates to lists. I used this for the navigation bar at the top of the page:

```
 li {
        float: left;
    }

        li a {
            font-family: 'Rye',cursive;
            font-size: 20px;
            display: block;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a, .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 8px 61.25px;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: black;
        }

            li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
                background-color: indianred;
            }

            li a:hover {
                background-color: indianred;
            }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
        }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        padding: 12px 16px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color: white;
            }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: The problem does not occur when I run that code. You have not included the *relevant piece* of your CSS.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing? Sounds like there's some additional CSS effecting your layout. So if you have other CSS being applied please share.

Comment: `li {
        float: left;
    }` is the culprit.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Mr Lister got it; it was my

```
li {
  float: left;
}
```